# ASIO - TCP Socket never getting data

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

My problem is that I don't seem to be ever receiving the packets I send as the `available()` function always returns 0. I am using the standalone version of Asio on Windows. I am not a complete newbie and have used ASIO before (but I'm still pretty terrible).

I have tried opening moveSoc beforehand but that didn't help. I also have tried binding endPoint to acceptor but that results in an invalid argument error.

**Set Up**

```
asio::error_code errCode;

asio::ip::address oponentAdress = checkPoint.address(); //Adress of a valid UDP endpoint
std::cout << checkPoint.address().to_string() << std::endl;
endPoint.address(oponentAdress);
endPoint.port(portNum);

acceptor->listen();
moveSoc.connect(endPoint, errCode);

std::cout << errCode.message() << std::endl;
acceptor->accept(moveSoc, errCode);
std::cout << errCode.message() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Found Client!" << std::endl;
```

**Sending code**

```
void ClientHandler::Outbound()
{
    moveSoc.write_some(asio::buffer(m_outgoingPacs, m_packetNum)); //Packet num is a valid number
}
```

**Reading code**

```
bool ClientHandler::Inbound()
{
    uint bytesToRead = moveSoc.available();

    if (bytesToRead > 0)
        moveSoc.read_some(asio::buffer(m_incomingPacs, bytesToRead));
    return (bytesToRead > 0);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing here that either sends or receives data. Unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Sorry about that, is that more readable?

Comment: No it isn't. Please use code formatting for code, and please *post* the code, not a description of what you think it does. The difference between what it does and what you think it does could entirely explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am really not quite with it today. If there are any more changes I could make to make my code or my question more readable let me know.

Comment: Your `ClientHandler::Inbound()` method is poorly designed. It needs to return three separate things: a read count > 0, end of stream, or an error indication. You can't sensibly compress that to a `bool`. You should return the read count itself, as returned by `moveSoc.read_some()`. And if you're using blocking mode there is rarely any sense in calling `available()`. For one thing you will never detect end of stream correctly.

Comment: Doesn't read_some() close its input stream when its done? The inbound function returns a bool purely for testing purposes I don't ever need how many packets I have actually read in. Is blocking mode a set option by default? As I said my knowledge of ASIO is documentary and the documentation is light enough that I can't understand how most of the functions are implemented low level. I lack the technical knowledge to be able to trove through the source code and get an Idea of what its doing.

Comment: I have no idea what `read_some()` does, but what you suggest doesn't sound even slightly likely. You're calling it anyway: why would it close its input in one circumstance and not the other? I'm just going from first principles of network programming for TCP: `available()` is useless, `read()` has three possible result states; ... I suspect that `available()` is always returning zero, which would prevent you from ever reading anything. Just block in the read.

Comment: From the tiny amount of ASIO I have programmed before `read_some()` and `write_some()`  from what I understand are merely safe versions of `send()` and `receive()` it was advised that the former won't go out of memory bounds so I tried that. I should have mentioned this before but like the numpty I am I forgot, yes `available()` always returns 0 but if I write to the socket and the connection is valid then I'm not sure why it wouldn't return how many bytes are available in the socket? If you have another design or resource that has better code then I will be happy to rewrite this monstrosity.

Comment: As long as you are using `available` for reading there is no need to discuss further. Remove that from your code and update it here.

Comment: As it stands, this question feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  An explanation of what is trying to be accomplished and an accompanying  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would greatly help (this is often very different than just posting one's existing code).  Also, for memory bounds, all Asio operations are only as safe as the buffers they are provided (i.e. `read_some()` and `receive()` provide the same level of safety).